# Images not appearing when running from APK

Tags: android, react-native, apk, android-image

This issue relates to Android.

We have recently migrated our *react-native* project ***from Expo to bare workflow***. We have an issue however whereby images are not loading when running the built apk file.

When debugging on an emulator or device using `react-native android` everything works fine. However on a built apk images simply do not appear.

Our build is being conducted as follows

```
react-native bundle --platform android /
     --dev false /
     --entry-file index.js 
     --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/app.bundle 
     --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
android/gradlew -p android clean
android/gradlew -p android assembleRelease
```

I can see that the first step bundles our images into the following directory

```
android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi
```

The project structure looks like this

```
index.js
App.js
   ios/
   android/
   app/
      assets/
         package.json
         images/
            image01.png
            image02.png
      screens/
         MyScreen.js
```

`app/assets/package.json` to allow us to avoid absolute paths contains

```
{ 
   "name": "@assets" 
}
```

and within MyScreen.js we have, within the `render()` method

```
   <Image source={require('@assets/images/image01.png')} />
```

Unpacking the built apk (`app-release.apk`) I can see that the images are referenced in the `MANIFEST.MF` file

```
/release/app-release/META-INF
```

like so

```
Name: res/drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_image01.png
SHA-256-Digest: [BLAH]

Name: res/drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_image02.png
SHA-256-Digest: [BLAH]
```

within `release/app-release/res/drawable-mdpi-v4`

the images are present and accounted for having the same name as the manifest.

So I am utterly confused as to why they do not display when running the apk on a device.

This is not an uncommon issue and there are several other Stack Overflow issues along this vein, however I have gone through all of them and none of the suggested solutions work for us.

Gradle version=5.6.3

RN version=61.5

Comment: A similar issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9451

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the code where you render your **Image** ?

And also can you post a picture of your folder structure ?

Because the path to the files are not the same depending on whether we work in debug or in release.

Comment: I've augmented the question above to hopefully include information necessary to diagnose this issue. Let me know if I can add anything further that may assist.

Comment: Normaly it must work with : ` <Image source={require('**../assets/images/image01.png**')} />`

Comment: I can assure you that this has been tried to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution will only affect those who are ejecting their project from Expo to a bare workflow. By attaching an onError handler to the image we observed the message to be

```
/data/user/0/[OUR_NAMESPACE]/files/.expo-internal/drawable-mdpi
/image001.png (No such file or directory)
```

So the issue is the path was being augmented to point to `.expo-internal` despite running a bare workflow. I've seen a commentator describe Expo as being like a crazy ex-girlfriend you can't seem to get rid off. Harsh, we love Expo, however I can totally see where he's coming from.

We were using only one package from the `@expo` module being `@expo/vector-icons` because it wasn't giving us any noticable trouble. But sure enough migrating over to `react-native-vector-icons` fixed the problem.

For those facing similar issues migrating to a bare workflow from the warm bosom of Expo be sure that you're not pulling in any modules from `@expo`. The unimodules beginning `expo-[MODULE_NAME]` on the other hand should be absolutely safe to use.